# UIDatePicker with minimum time

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing for ios and I'm in the making of a `UITextField` containing `UIDatePicker` as its `inputView`.
My problem is as follows: I have set the minimum time to now --> `[NSDate date]` and that's because I don't want the user to enter a time that is before `now`.
This works fine, but if the user stays in the ViewController for when a time passes in the phone, I get a wrong time (1 minute before `now`).
Is there a way to listen to the hardware clock, and sync with the phone's clock? like listen to the iPhone's (hopefully) notification for changing the minute?
I don't want the user to see wrong time, I want the text field to change if the time passes.

 I thought of an implementation and I'd like to hear another perspective since mine is not easy at all...

**My implementation**:

1. run a delayed GCD async for the seconds left in the current minute, and when that reaches, listen for every 60 seconds... but this doesn't seems like the right idea, since if the user leaves the ViewController I might get a leak or user puts the app in the background, it'll be frozen and continue from the wrong place (According to GCD documentation).

 Any suggestion will be very appreciated.

Comment: What's it for? If the date is in the past can you just change to the current date when the user triggers?

Comment: I want the text field to keep in sync if the current time is after the time set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using GDC, take a similar approach but with `NSTimer`. `invalidate` the timer when the view is hidden (`viewDidDisappear:`) and observe app notifications for going to the background and returning to the foreground to reset your timer.

---

You need to calculate the end of the next minute, this becomes the first fire date (`fireDate`). Once you have that:

```
NSTimer *timer = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:fireDate interval:60 target:self selector:@selectior(...) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
```

Comment: I see what you mean, never used `NSTimer` before, could you show how to initialize it to call when a minute passes? given that it can be even now? and a recurrence after only?

Comment: Added some more, will leave you to calculate the fire date (hint: `NSDateComponents`).

Answer (score 0):

Configure your date picker behind a getter or a method of it's own and do something like this, in the UITextField delegate

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = self.datePicker;
    datePicker.minimumDate = [NSDate date];
    textField.inputView = datePicker;

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: You didn't quite understand me, I'd like the uitextfield to be updated as the time goes by, so the user will get the correct value even if he isn't clicking the uitextfield

Comment: Ah ok.  Well you can set up a timer that update the UIDatePicker directly, if you leave a pointer for it somewhere, but I would have a re-think about whether you want to actually do this.

Comment: I wouldn't encourage constantly updating a view that the user is supposed to manipulate themselves.  Let them choose, and check what they have chosen, afterwards.

Comment: I'm setting the default time as the current time, I just want it to keep in track of the current time, and if the user sets a time, and it passes because of long staying, to keep track of it

Comment: Maybe set the minimum date of the picker view each time the user selects something.

Comment: So in -(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component set it there, or react to the users choice if it is in the past

Comment: yes , i agree with @Nashy_ , just correct the minimum time when user select data picker row.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but that's not the UX I'm going for.